# VBA Macro that filters on specific column "U" if column U has data or a date it deletes the entire row

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, Macro. I want the macro to filter on column "U" preferably with column name "Vessel Departed from Port of Loading" if this column has a date or data then delete the entire corresponding row.
My codes below it do not work... Please help I have pasted code and excel screen below for ref

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POL").Range("U").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
Rows(2).Select

Rows(1).AutoFilter
 
'Create a variable that = the last used row in column U
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
 
'Create a looping variable # to go backwards from the last used Row# to 1
For i = lr To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "U").Value < #1/3/2009# Or Cells(i, "U").Value > #2/3/2010# Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

[image: Excel Column U]

Like if column U "Vessel Departed from Port of Loading" is having data or date then delete the entire corresponding rows too. Instead of giving a column number "U" column name "Vessel Departed from Port of Loading" would be better because column number may vary... please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a macro that will delete anything NOT blank on col "U" (or column21), INCLUDING the entire row, in sheets called "POL"

Based on your description I would do the following:

```
Option Explicit

Dim wb As Workbook

Dim sRng As Range
Dim fRng As Range

Dim cel As Range

Dim tRow As Long 
Dim fCol As Long


Sub foo()
    
    'setting wb as thisworkbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    'row 1 assigned into fRng(find range) object
    Set fRng = wb.Sheets("POL").Rows(1).Find(what:="Vessel Departed from Port of Loading", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
    'gets fRng range object, and assigns its column property value into fCol variable
    fCol = fRng.Column
    

    'finding the last row for column 1, make sure you select a col that covers the whole data set, based on last row
    tRow = wb.Sheets("POL").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'assigning range based on col index based on str search(fCol) + total row count (tRow) in sRng range object
    With wb.Sheets("POL")
    
        Set sRng = .Range(.Cells(1, fCol), .Cells(tRow, fCol))
    
    End With
    
    'call sub deltR, the function does a filter based on range, string, and col number passed as argument.
    'passing arguments: range (sRng), delete anything not empty, on col#1 (sRng has only one range = columns("U:U" + tRow)
    Call deltR(sRng, "<>", 1)


End Sub





Private Sub deltR(ByRef sRng As Range, ByVal aStr As String, ByVal f As Integer)

    'this sub procedure looks for a string (aStr) passed in (sRng) range object range, based on col number (f)
    With sRng

        .AutoFilter field:=f, Criteria1:=aStr
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

    End With

    wb.Sheets("POL").AutoFilterMode = False

    Set sRng = Nothing

End Sub
```

just run sub procedure "foo()" to run the script.

I named the sheet "POL" based on the code you wrote above. I do not know how your workbook is structured. so I took a guess based on your explanation

Give it a try and get back to me in the comments to fix possible issues.

UPDATE: Please check again, I created an extra range object that searches row 1 for "Vessel Departed from Port of Loading" string, and returns the col index
also I have removed the "set wb = nothing" at the end. I think maybe it was causing the error I read in the comments.

Give it a try one more time and please let me know if you have questions.

Thanks

Comment: Perfect @Victor Song this it has worked! However, it had stopped looping at "wb.Sheets("POL").AutoFilterMode = False" wherein I gave/changed code to "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POL").AutoFilterMode = False" after this has worked properly...
However, instead of giving the column number "U1:U" I wanted to mention the column name i.e. "Vessel Departed from Port of Loading" because the column number U1:U may vary so better to give a column name based on which it further deletes the data.... I would be highly obliged if you could help me with this. Thanks again.

Comment: I saw on your description, and saw that comment coming. There is a way to find column position based on string. If you are looking for a column with a name "Vessel Departed from Port Loading" the script can be implemented. I will update the script and send it to you

Comment: Please see update, I have  created an extra range object that searches row 1 for "Vessel Departed from Port of Loading" string, and returns the col index. Now the script will find the col containing "Vessel (...) Loading" and search for non-blanks and deletes entirerow.

Comment: Hi @Victor Song I have posted 1 more query today on which I am struggling... I would be glad if you could check and help me on that... Query title is "Filter on specific column and delete all data with future date" 
Thanks